# How can I run .php, .aspx on same site ubuntu 10.04

Tags: php, asp.net, ubuntu-10.04

I installed ModMono using the reference:
http://ubuntuexperiment.wordpress.com/2009/01/29/running-aspnet-applications-in-ubuntu-using-modmono/

Now I am able to run .aspx pages, but if I try to run .php files its not working.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i got the solution & it worked for me nicely.....

this article helped me to run both .net and .php for the same site.

http://studentguru.gr/b/kingherc/archive/2008/05/22/how-to-mono-1-9-1-and-php-5-on-ubuntu-8-04-hardy.aspx